# Field $\mathbb F_2$, Reducible and irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

In a lecture on ring theory, we stated that if $K$ is a field, then $K[X]$ is factorial and then looked at examples of polynomials in $K[X]$ (for instance for $K=\mathbb C$). Then we chose $K=\mathbb F_2$. We wrote down: $$(X-a)(X-b) = \begin{cases}X^2, \text{if} \ a=0=b, \\ X^2+X, \text{if} \ a=1, b = 0 \ \text{and vice versa}, \\ X^2+1, \text{if}\ a = 1 = b.\end{cases} $$

We continued by stating that $X^2+X+1$ would be irreducible over $F_2$, since this polynomial doesn't appear in the above list. But if $a=1$ and $b=0$, then the factor $(X-0)$ is a unit, or I am mistaken? Therefore - at least for me - the above list does not necessarily state all the reducible polynomials with degree $2$ ...

Clarification would really be appreciated!

Kind regards, 
MathIsFun

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you saying that you think $X^2+X+1$ is reducible? (With $a=1$, $b=0$, one gets $X^2+X$, as the displayed equation states.)

Comment: $X-0$ is not a unit, the only unit in this ring is $1$.

Comment: What is your definition of a unit?

Answer (score -1):

$X = X-0$ is not a unit.  if it were, there would be an $f(X) \in \Bbb{F}_2[X]$ such that $X f(X) = 1$, but this product always produces a polynomial one degree higher than that of $f$.

For a general field of coefficients, one should take care of units, which in $F[x]$ are the nonzero elements of $F$, again by arguing through degrees.  However when the field is $\Bbb{F}_2$, there is only one unit and it is adequately represented in the list of possible factorizations you have written.

Comment: I am still not quite convinced yet: Why isn't $X-0$ a unit in $\mathbb F_2$? I thought that $1_{\mathbb F_2} = \text{id}: \mathbb F_2 \rightarrow \mathbb F_2, X \mapsto X$ ...

Comment: An element of a ring is a unit if it has a cofactor giving $1$.  This is literally what is in the first sentence of the answer.  What you have written in your comment is slightly confused because you are using $X$ to represent an arbitrary element of $\Bbb{F}_2$ and to represent an unrelated transcendental extension of $\Bbb{F}_2$.  You should *not* think of $X$ as a variable taking values in the field -- extensions by indeterminates do not incorporate evaluation maps.

Comment: Further question: I do not understand the last part of your answer (I don't mean your comment) yet. Obviously, the only unit of $\mathbb F_2$ is $1$. But what then is the unit of $\mathbb F_2[X]$?

Comment: @MathIsFun : Also only $1$.  No matter what you multiply a given polynomial by, its degree does not decrease.  The only unit is $1$, having degree $0$.  If you start with any polynomial having degree $\geq 1$, no cofactor can lower its degree, so the given polynomial cannot be a unit.  (Note that, when you consider quotients of rings of polynomials, the equivalence classes of units in the field of coefficients will also contain polynomials, so the notion of degree is less clear in a quotient.)

Comment: Ok, I guess it slowly makes sense ... Formally, I saw in a textbook that if $R$ is a ring, then $R[X]$ is defined  as a sequence $(a_0, a_1, \dots, a_i, 0, 0, 0, \dots), \exists i\in\mathbb N: a_i=0$. So formally, $(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dots)\in \mathbb F_2[X]$ is the unit, I guess. But then we write $1:=(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dots)$, which is just a definition.